# ADB debugging in Android Studio - some basic issues

Tags: android-studio, adb

Ok, I've squeaked by not needing to use ADB in the Studio, since back
in the 'beta' days of AS. (Just lucky, I guess.)  But now, I need to
debug a crashing app.

I've gotten this far:
  Learned how to put adb.exe on my Window's 'PATH' 
  (so that it's invokable from cmd-window):
     My path-entry was: C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools

Am assuming that 'logcat' lives on Android device (I was incorrectly guessing it lives on the development machine).  I'm assuming this, because when I dis-connect
the USB-cable and enter 'adb logcat' is says waiting for device.

Ok, now my (next) issue: When I fire up the app-being-developed, I'm getting
"Unfortunately  has stopped"...which I'm assuming is an app-crash.

And, while I'm looking at 'logcat', I can see a stack-trace flow by.  But
as I try to scroll-back to read it, logcat keeps dribbling in more data.
So, how do I tell it to shutup...so that I can look at a static copy
of logcat and see what has happened (without more data dribbling in)?

[If there is other beginner related info, beyond this question, feel free to
to add that info...I'm clearly in need of basic 'adb-related' enlightenment.]

TIA.

Cheers...